# get associated Phone number with SIM

Tags: android

How can i get Phone number associated with SIM for CMDA and GSM and service provider name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android TelephonyManager, may not return the number in all cases. It may not return the number in case the Operator has not set it, You will have to create a verification scenario in which the you ask the user to enter a number, then send an SMS to verify it

Comment: could you tell me how? Where do i need to send the sms to set the phone no in my device?

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you want is in the TelephonyManager class:

[Android TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

for instance, getLine1Number() returns the gsm phone number

Comment: perfect. do you have any idea about CDMA?

Comment: What Azlam is saying below is correct. There isn't a guarantee that the number is always there. Any information about the phone that's available is in that class or else you need to do something like what Azlam is suggesting afaik.

Comment: But how i get it. I mean where do i send the sms thus i can get the phone no by code??Please help..