# How to get my phonenumber

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to get my phone number...
the .getLine1Number() returns null,
is there any alternative?

Comment: have a look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515361/get-associated-phone-number-with-sim/5516082#5516082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be several reasons...

Are you using an emulator? If so then it won't have an phone number

Are you using a tablet? Same as above

Have you added this permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Are you using the correct code?

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: Keep it mind that the value returned by `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()` may be null ; not all phone carrier set it.