# How to get Phone number of android device using Sim card or

Tags: android

My code is here, it is always throwing null

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

I used the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Please give me exact solution to get phone number. Thank you.

Comment: duplicate of [get associated Phone number with SIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515361/get-associated-phone-number-with-sim) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705403/retrieving-phone-number-from-sim-card-error and others